# Retrofit2 - Cannot upload file with PartMap

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, image-uploading

I have this files, interface and the process.
Im trying to upload an image to server, but I it only send the form data. The is image gone, didnt uploaded. What did I do wrong?

```
public interface ClientRoute {    
 @Multipart
 @POST("attendance/in")
 Call < DataAttendance > inAttendance(
  @PartMap Map < String, RequestBody > partMap,
  @HeaderMap Map < String, String > headers);
}
```

This `void` require time date from third-party datetime API, and if success the program do the upload process. This code is working, but only the form data like text.

```
public void inAttendance(int userId, String token, int storeId, String timeAttendance, String photoPath, int refId,
 double latitude, double longitude) {

 timeController.getTimeaAsync("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", false, new TimeInterface() {
  @Override
  public void onSuccess(@NonNull String value) {

   Map < String, RequestBody > params = new HashMap < > ();
   params.put("storeId", requestBody(String.valueOf(storeId)));
   params.put("time_attendance", requestBody(value));
   params.put("refId", requestBody(String.valueOf(refId)));
   params.put("photo", RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), photoPath));
   params.put("latitude", requestBody(String.valueOf(latitude)));
   params.put("longitude", requestBody(String.valueOf(longitude)));

   Map < String, String > headers = new HashMap < > ();
   headers.put("userId", String.valueOf(userId));
   headers.put("token", token);


   clientRoute = ClientUtils.getClientRoute();
   clientRoute.inAttendance(params, headers).enqueue(new Callback < DataAttendance > () {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call < DataAttendance > call, Response < DataAttendance > response) {
     Log.i(TAG, "Response code: " + response.raw().code() + "\r\n" +
      "Request url: " + response.raw().request().url() + "\r\n");
     if (!response.isSuccessful() || response.body() == null) {
      try {
       Log.e(TAG, response.errorBody().string());
      } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return;
     }

     DataAttendance dataAttendance = response.body();

     if (dataAttendance.getStatusCode() == 0) {
      return;
     }

     Toast.makeText(context, "Attendance ID: " + dataAttendance.getStatusCode(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call < DataAttendance > call, Throwable t) {
     Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: " + t);
    }
   });
  }

  @Override
  public void onError(@NonNull Throwable throwable) {

  }
 }, false);
}

private RequestBody requestBody(String value) {
 return RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), value);
}
```

I tried finding missing parameters or typos but i didn't found it. All the parameters needed to server are correct. But the image file won't uploaded. Is anyone willing to help me? I really appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

use this code to get Image path

```
 File file = new File(String.valueOf(uriFilePath.getPath()));
        RequestBody requestFile =
                RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);

        MultipartBody.Part body =
                MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", file.getName(), requestFile);
```

in API Interface

```
@Part MultipartBody.Part image
```

Comment: I did this, from many example codes. And I got request timeout

Comment: use debug :)
because I don't find anything wrong here

Comment: i dont even know how to use debug on android studio.. I only know on netbeans, cus its different..

Answer (score 0):

I think you can not get the image file from storage successfully. so, please check my below code link

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56846740/5435259

Comment: you might be right, I saved the image file in /data directory which has read-only permission.